# jssor slider different transitions

Tags: dynamic, transition, slide, jssor

I have 5 different slides, the first four slides with the same transition, only the last slide should act with a different transition.
I have defined the transitions in the _SlideshowTransitions arrays, shown here:

```
var _SlideshowTransitions = [

    {$Duration:1000,$Opacity:2,$Brother:{$Duration:800,$Opacity:2}},
    {$Duration:1000,$Opacity:2,$Brother:{$Duration:800,$Opacity:2}},
    {$Duration:1000,$Opacity:2,$Brother:{$Duration:800,$Opacity:2}},
    {$Duration:1000,$Opacity:2,$Brother:{$Duration:800,$Opacity:2}},
    {$Duration:1200,x:-0.3,$During:{$Left:[0.3,0.7]},$Easing:{$Left:$JssorEasing$.$EaseInCubic,$Opacity:$JssorEasing$.$EaseLinear},$Opacity:2}

];
```

Works great as long as you do not use the navigation arrows or bullets! How can I allocate the one different transition to the one special slide ?

thanks in advance
JD

Answer (score 0):

You can use api `$SetSlideshowTransitions` to set slideshow transitions dynamically anytime.

```
var jssor_slider1 = new $JssorSlider$("slider1_container", options);

function SetSlideshowTransition() {
    switch (jssor_slider1.$CurrentIndex()) {
        case 3:
            jssor_slider1.$SetSlideshowTransitions([{$Duration:1200,x:-0.3,$During:{$Left:[0.3,0.7]},$Easing:{$Left:$JssorEasing$.$EaseInCubic,$Opacity:$JssorEasing$.$EaseLinear},$Opacity:2}]);
            break;
         default:
            jssor_slider1.$SetSlideshowTransitions([{$Duration:1000,$Opacity:2,$Brother:{$Duration:800,$Opacity:2}}]);
            break;
    }
}

jssor_slider1.$On($JssorSlider$.$EVT_PARK, SetSlideshowTransition);
```

Comment: I modified the switch statement -> switch (jssor_slider1.$CurrentIndex()) { ...
works excellent now, thanks!